# HTML Javascript: stop current playback if another one is started

Tags: javascript, html, audio

Consider this code:

```
var currentPlayback = "";

function playSound(elem) {
    var str = elem.id;
    currentPlayback = str;

    if (elem.counter === undefined) {
        elem.counter = 0;
    }

    // Problem is here: Should check for current playback and act accordingly
    if (currentPlayback !== str) {
        lib[currentPlayback].stopAudio();
    }

        // Play/Stop
        if (elem.counter === 0) {
            lib[str].playAudio();
            elem.counter = 1;
        } else {
            lib[str].stopAudio();
            elem.counter = 0;
        }
}
```

I'm trying to do a sound system where for each button clicked, a sound is played. Im using a obj called lib (library) which holds all the sound files. They all have a function for starting and stoping the playback. It's working great by far and Im almost finished. Problem is, I want to make the current playback stop, if another button is clicked. Tried to store into a global and then change it everytime the function is called, but it doesn't work. The sounds are just overlapping ontop of eachother.

Thanks in advance!
Cheers

Comment: Did you see that you do `currentPlayback = str` and just after `if (currentPlayback !== str)`? How do you expect them to be different?

Comment: I noticed that too and placed it after the if statement, still doesn't work :/
(playback isn't happening at all)